# jenkins multiproject environment fails running same code as regular job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-multibranch

here are the contents of the Jenkinsfile:

```
node {
git branch: '$BRANCH_NAME', credentialsId: 'IDIDID', url: 'git@bitbucket.org:SOMEPLACE.git'
sh '''printenv
ls
pwd
cd somedir
virtualenv tmp
source tmp/bin/activate
pip install -e .
pip install tox
make test-ci'''
}
```

The error:

```
+ pip install -e .
/home/jenkins/workspace/_JenkinsMultiProjectSupport-KR5YXE6UBANUWSMX2TC4P4IVPW3CHEACQ3YZEOLKRLGWNJAFAA4Q@tmp/durable-9edef277/script.sh: /home/jenkins/workspace/_JenkinsMultiProjectSupport-KR5YXE6UBANUWSMX2TC4P4IVPW3CHEACQ3YZEOLKRLGWNJAFAA4Q/SOMEDIR/tmp/bin/pip: /home/jenkins/workspace/_JenkinsMultiProjectSupport-KR5YXE6UBANUWSMX2TC4P4IVPW: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

how are jenkins envs in multi branch projects different from regular envs?

Answer (score 0):

So Apparently the extra long path was the issue with virtualenv